# Problem with greek letters in latex font (Computer Modern) in Inkscape

Tags: greek, inkscape

I use Inkscape for my graphics in my latex document. As the font in the graphics should be the same as the text font (CMR10), I installed computer modern on my computer. Regular letters work fine. Greek letters don't appear, but they are there. When I change the font to a non-CM font (e.g. Arial), they appear. When I change it back to CM, they disappear.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, the greek symbols are not in the cmr font. Maybe cmmi.

Comment: cmr really only works with Tex (and only has 127 characters so has no lowercase greek and the uppercase Greek is not where any other program will expect to find it) use the opentype latin-modern font to get a cm-style font with a more modern font technology that other programs understand

Comment: Have you tried using `\usepackage{lmodern}` ?